# Error using gnuplot from within Sage, but works fine in regular Python

Tags: python, gnuplot, sage

I apologize if this isn't the best place to ask this question, but hopefully someone here can help.  I want to run some gnuplot commands directly from within a Sage script, but I get the following error message:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
>   Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/gnuplot
>   Reason: Incompatible library version: gnuplot requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 10.0.0

This message appears if I try to use the gnuplotpy interface in Sage, or if I just use something like os.system("gnuplot -e \"plot('sin(x)')\"") from Sage.  However, the same os.system(...) command works just fine in regular python.  Many thanks.

Comment: compare PATH inside Sage and in the Python script.

Comment: In sage:  sage: os.environ.get('PATH')
'/Applications/Sage-4.7-OSX-64bit-10.6.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin:/Applications/Sage-4.7-OSX-64bit-10.6.app/Contents/Resources/sage:/Applications/Sage-4.7-OSX-64bit-10.6.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin', and in the regular shell I get the same thing without the /Applications/sage directories.

Comment: Just FYI, there is also http://ask.sagemath.org/ and the sage-support mailing list where you can ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sage changes a number of environments including `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc.  This can cause problems running binaries not installed inside Sage.  For this reason it provides a shell command `sage-native-execute` which (mostly) changes all the variables back.  So try the following—it fixes the problem for me:

```python
os.system('''sage-native-execute gnuplot -e "plot('sin(x)')"''')
```